# SailsJS: Many-to-Many association in MySQL

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, sails.js, waterline

I've tried to search before posting this question, but no success.

I'm having some troubles trying to understand the best way to achieve a many-to-many association in SailsJS.

Ex:

> Hospital has many specialties
>
> Specialty has many hospitals

How do I represent the tables in MySQL so the SailsJS operate on them?

I have an **Hospital** table and a **Specialty** table.
Do I have to have an **Hospital_Specialty** (not sure about if this is the correct tablename to use) table to handle those associations? Like:

> **Hospital_Specialty**
>
> id: int
>
> hospital_id: int
>
> specialty_id: int

I've read the documention but no luck on getting a proper way to achieve what I need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: My initial answer was totally wrong.

The documentation for setting up many <-> many relationships is here:
[Many-to-Many | Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many)

First of all, you'll want to work in Waterline rather than mysql to get this to work properly.
You can set up a many relationship in your model like so:

#### Specialty.js Model

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    hospitals:{
      collection: 'hospital',
      via: 'specialties'
    }
  }
}
```

#### Hospital.js Model

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    specialties:{
      collection: 'specialty',
      via: 'hospitals'
    }
  }
}
```

This will set up the required intermediate tables.

Up to you if you want to use plurals or not.

Comment: So you are telling me that Waterline will deal with the relationship by itself and create/edit the table to accomodate the relation?

Comment: Yes.
[Models as used by Sails](https://www.evernote.com/l/ACYDwBR3trZG86EBzYLDH_H3MqNTfsX-E6M)
[Tables as seen in db](https://www.evernote.com/l/ACZTe2PDsCtP9Ji9aOab4fTjdoRJrdq8UWg)

Comment: The examples above are using Postgres, but the concepts remain the same.

Comment: I think I'm having a problem with sequences... ``ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'institution.specialties' in 'field list'
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError ...``
What am I doing wrong? I've defined the models as you said (used Instituiton model instead of Hospital but its the same).

Comment: I think Waterline sometimes tries to connect the two before the second table is built. Try commenting out the foreign key collections in both models, lifting (so it builds both tables) then uncommenting and lifting again (to link the two together).
Hopefully they fix this soon!

Comment: Sorry but it was a PEBKAC... I wasn't doing the things in the right way... I was writing 'model' instead of 'collection'. Thanks for all! :)